# General error: 1005 Can't create table - Laravel 4.2 can't create foreign key

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I'm trying to create a table and add foreign key but it only creates the table but it doesn't add foreign key. I got this error message:

`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'myDB.#sql
  -4b4_1a5e43' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table`forms`add constr
  aint forms_id_foreign foreign key (`id`) references`pages`(`
  id`))

My migration looks like that:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('forms', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->string('id')->nullable();
            $table->string('url', 100);
            $table->string('title', 100);

            $table->timestamps();


        });
        Schema::table('forms', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('pages');

        });
    }
```

My table `forms` doesn't have Primary key. It should have `id` column that is foreign key references `id` on `pages` table.

I've searched for that problem and added `nullable()` to the `id` column and

`$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

to migration  but still no result.

Where I am wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

after some workout i was able to find out what's the problem and how to solve it. as its a string field sql allows indexed string type foreign keys. so add index to the id field.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('forms', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('url', 100);
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('pages');

        });
    }
```

same way index the  make the pages table id column. you said me you don't have migration file. just go to the db and add **index** to the **id** field. after that run the above mentioned migration. tested and works fine. if you create a migration file for pages make the id column like this

```
    Schema::create('pages', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('id')->nullable()->index();
    .........
```

Comment: pages table exists, that's not the case. But now, I need to create the `forms` table - and this column name should be `id` becase there are 2 much more tables similar to `forms` table and they should have the same column structure and in these tables column is `id`

Comment: @mistery_girl can you edit the question with both pages and forms migrations? i have updated answer

Comment: In my question, I've added migration for `forms` table but there is no migration for `pages` table. It has been made without migration when project was started and I don't know how to make it now.

Comment: @mistery_girl is id column data type string/varchar on the pages table ? it should be same as i mentioned in answer

Comment: yes, it is varchar, the same type as column `id` in `forms` table.

Comment: @mistery_girl check my answer.. updated and it should work now. i have tested it :)

Comment: But column `id` is not integer, it is `string`. I tried this -> I added `$table->string('id')->nullable()->index();` but it still shows the same error.

Comment: @mistery_girl sorry..i forgot to change it..let me change..it should be string

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've tried it in this way and no result. I've had difficulty with laravel migrations when adding foreign keys. I think problem is not column type.